# Google App Script not printing list items in required format

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I have this list

```
mylist = ['SHIMLA', 'TIKKAR', 'GSSS PUJARLI-4', 'GHS SERI', '31.19041597', '77.62639507', '2197', '20', 'f', 'Level1', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Level2', 'Yes', 'Good', 'Good', 'Good', '1', 'http://ab0db3c8f0b1:8080/view/binaryData?blobKey=BRCC_V1%5B%40version%3Dnull+and+%40uiVersion%3Dnull%5D%2FBRCCs_QM_Question%5B%40key%3Duuid%3A4814099a-f9ba-4f1d-abcb-8e8ddd4a0fe1%5D%2FAcademic_interventions%3ALOCharts_Image', '2', 'Yes', 'Not_Applicable', '1', '1', '1', '2', 'Yes', 'No', '', '2', '0', 'NA', 'No']
```

And when I print them like this:

```
var end = mylist.length;

  for (x=1; x<=end; x+=1){
        Logger.log(mylist[x]);
  }
```

It prints them like this:

```
[19-10-11 14:06:49:454 IST] '
[19-10-11 14:06:49:455 IST] S
[19-10-11 14:06:49:455 IST] H
[19-10-11 14:06:49:456 IST] I
[19-10-11 14:06:49:457 IST] M
[19-10-11 14:06:49:457 IST] L
[19-10-11 14:06:49:458 IST] A
[19-10-11 14:06:49:459 IST] '
[19-10-11 14:06:49:459 IST] ,
[19-10-11 14:06:49:459 IST]  
[19-10-11 14:06:49:460 IST] '
[19-10-11 14:06:49:461 IST] T
[19-10-11 14:06:49:461 IST] I
[19-10-11 14:06:49:462 IST] K
[19-10-11 14:06:49:463 IST] K
[19-10-11 14:06:49:463 IST] A
[19-10-11 14:06:49:464 IST] R
[19-10-11 14:06:49:465 IST] '
[19-10-11 14:06:49:465 IST] ,
[19-10-11 14:06:49:466 IST]
```

Instead of printing them like this:

```
TIKKAR,
GSSS PUJARLI-4,
GHS SERI,
31.19041597,
77.62639507,
2197,
20,
f,
Level1,
```

How to make it print in the required format?

I've received this `mylist` as payload from a request.

Also my aim is to do this:

```
for (x=1; x<=end; x+=1){
    body.replaceText('<' + x + '>', mylist[x]);
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `mylist = ['SHIMLA', 'TIKKAR'...'No']` and not `mylist = "['SHIMLA', 'TIKKAR'...'No']"`?

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure.

Comment: Then you have an error somewhere else, your code works perfectly for me. Show us more code.

Comment: It's working now. I converted the data to json before sending it to the api. Then parsed the data on receiving. I don't know how, but it is working now. @Toto

Comment: If you haven't problem anymore, you should consider deleting your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems your list is a string not array. eg- "['SHIMLA', 'TIKKAR'.......]"

   you may convert that back to an array:

   ```
   var mylistArr = mylist.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(", ")
   ```
2. Why your loop starts from 1st index? (x=1) it should be 0 if the data would be a correct array.

Comment: @mplungjan Does voting up closes ? :)

Comment: Okay, I'll convert it back to list.
I want to get values from index 1 that's why the loop starts from index 1.

Comment: @Rishabh so the problem was point-1.  ok, you can now change your string to array.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the code to:

```js
mylist = ['SHIMLA', 'TIKKAR', 'GSSS PUJARLI-4', 'GHS SERI', '31.19041597', '77.62639507', '2197', '20', 'f', 'Level1', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Level2', 'Yes', 'Good', 'Good', 'Good', '1', 'http://ab0db3c8f0b1:8080/view/binaryData?blobKey=BRCC_V1%5B%40version%3Dnull+and+%40uiVersion%3Dnull%5D%2FBRCCs_QM_Question%5B%40key%3Duuid%3A4814099a-f9ba-4f1d-abcb-8e8ddd4a0fe1%5D%2FAcademic_interventions%3ALOCharts_Image', '2', 'Yes', 'Not_Applicable', '1', '1', '1', '2', 'Yes', 'No', '', '2', '0', 'NA', 'No']

mylist.forEach(function (x) {
    console.log(x);
})
```

seems to be working perfectly.

if you want you can now use 
`body.replaceText('<' + x + '>', x);`
inside the forEach function

Comment: This is a similar code than OP, it doesn't explain why OP code doesn't work. The problem is not that, read the comments below the question.

Comment: @Toto how are you related to the question? the person posted code and i showed him that it works with minor modification

Comment: @Toto why did you down voted my answer? that was uncalled for...

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your  answer deserves it. Your answer doesn't explain anything so, it is useless.

Comment: @Toto the question is not clear, the problem is the question not the answer...

Comment: @Toto just trying the help the guy, i am just starting a conversation

Comment: If the question seems unclear to you, ask OP for explanation/clarification in the comments, that's what there are for. Do not answer unclear question especially when the answer doesn't give usefull informations about the (unclear) question. In this case, they want to know **why** their code doesn't work, IMHO it' a typo but, within any further infos from OP, we can't give a 100% valid answer.

Comment: @Toto i would ask in the comments, unfortunately you have to have 50 reputation points in order to do that, and i don't have that yet. additionally i don't see why we can't let the OP answer and clarify his question, in the process of doing so i could edit my answer accordingly. the only problem with that is technical  because people might down vote my answer and my reputation might go down like what happen here...

Comment: may we please have some peace in here fellas